# Pick out link Ids form database with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, sqlite

Just learning ajax today and am stock somewhere. Trying to link my php links to work with ajax so the data with that link Id would be displayed without refreshing the page. Below are the codes of what I have tried.

**index.php**

```
    <div class="page">
    <ul>
    <?php
    $sql = <<<EOF
    SELECT * FROM addcategory ;
    EOF;
    $ret = $db->query($sql); 
    While ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
            $catname = $row['catname'];
            $catid = $row['catid'];

            echo "<li><a href='index.php?category_id=$catid'>$catname</a></li>";
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cat_question">response displays here</div>
```

**php script**

```
    require_once ("db.php");
    $db = new MyDb();

    $catid = (int)$_GET['category_id'];
    $csql = <<<EOF
    SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category_id = {$catid};

    $cret = $db->query($csql);
    While ($crow = $cret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    $catquestion = $crow['question'];
    $catans = $crow['answer'];

    echo "<div>$catquestion</div><p>$catans</p>";
   }
```

**JavaScript**

```
   $('.page a).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            If (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHTtpRequest();
            } else {
                    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    If (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var response = xhttp.responseText;
            $('.cat_question').html(response);
                    }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "category.php?category_id=$catid", true);
            xhttp.send();
    });
```

I know if i change the xhttp URL to category.php?category_id=1 or any id it works but that would mean in would have to write ajax request for each a tags. Please what is the way to solve this block. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using jQuery AND creating a Ajax request manually?

Comment: you realize that if that's your actual code for the heredoc, you're creating a parse error. Your JS appears to contain a syntax error in there also, which the code highlighter is picking up on. Use error reporting and look at your developer console. The heredoc appears to not be closed for the second one also.

Comment: @fred I can't seem to find any syntax errors in there.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` put that at the top of all your php files

Comment: Did that didn't get any errors. The thing is I have 4 Ids in my database which are foreign keys to another table. These id act as links to view topics under each id. The aim is to click on a particular id and then use ajax to request data with that particular id. I know how to achieve this with just php but didn't like the page refresh so ajax came to mind. The codes above have no errors probably d ajax cos I just learnt today. Is there a way of achieving this?